# Building Debian with Buildroot: libDeviceIo.so: file format not recognized

Tags: linux, embedded, arm64, buildroot

Im trying to compile for a project debian for this device: https://www.engicam.com/vis-prod/PX30-Core/PX30-Core-EDIMM-SOM-based-on-RockChip--PX30 which has an aarch64 architecture. I'm using a VM provided by them which should already have all the tools and configurations ready, but I'm running into some issues. If I've understood correctly I have to build buildroot to build Debian, after adding a couple packages with `make menuconfig` and running `make` I get this error:

```
PATH="/home/user/px30/buildroot/output/host/bin:/home/user/px30/buildroot/output/host/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin" /usr/bin/make -j9 CXXFLAGS+="-DRKDEVICEIO -I/home/user/px30/buildroot/../external/deviceio_release/DeviceIO/include" LFLAGS+=" -lDeviceIo -lasound" -C /home/user/px30/buildroot/output/build/qsetting-1.0
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/px30/buildroot/output/build/qsetting-1.0'
/home/user/px30/buildroot/output/host/bin/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu-g++ -lDeviceIo -lasound -o qsetting main.o mainwindow.o qtaudio.o qtbt.o qtfactory.o qtinputdialog.o qtkeyboard.o qtupdate.o qtwifi.o qrc_res.o moc_mainwindow.o moc_qtaudio.o moc_qtbt.o moc_qtfactory.o moc_qtinputdialog.o moc_qtkeyboard.o moc_qtupdate.o moc_qtwifi.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Multimedia -lQt5Gui -lQt5Network -lQt5Core -latomic -lrt -ldl /home/user/px30/buildroot/output/host/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libGLESv2.so -lpthread  -lrt -lpthread -ldl 
/home/user/px30/buildroot/output/host/lib/gcc/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/6.5.0/../../../../aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/bin/ld:/home/user/px30/buildroot/output/host/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/../lib64/libDeviceIo.so: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/home/user/px30/buildroot/output/host/lib/gcc/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/6.5.0/../../../../aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/bin/ld:/home/user/px30/buildroot/output/host/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/../lib64/libDeviceIo.so:0: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:214: recipe for target 'qsetting' failed
make[1]: *** [qsetting] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/px30/buildroot/output/build/qsetting-1.0'
package/pkg-generic.mk:254: recipe for target '/home/user/px30/buildroot/output/build/qsetting-1.0/.stamp_built' failed
make: *** [/home/user/px30/buildroot/output/build/qsetting-1.0/.stamp_built] Error 2
```

I tried to open `/px30/buildroot/output/host/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libDeviceIo.so` and it's an ASCII file

```
user@ubuntu:~/px30/buildroot/output/host/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib$ cat libDeviceIo.so 
fake
user@ubuntu:~/px30/buildroot/output/host/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib$ file libDeviceIo.so 
libDeviceIo.so: ASCII text
```

EDIT: I did not find a solution, I solved it by removing the package qsetting from the target packages

Comment: "If I've understood correctly I have to build buildroot to build Debian"  That doesn't sound correct to me.  But it's unclear how you got that impression or what your intention is.

Comment: I want to build Debian for my embedded device, hopefully adding the packages I need (mainly python 3), and I am follow the instruction provided. The manual says: 
`At the moment, to compile some applications in Debian, packages compiled by Buildroot will be used. So you need to build Buildroot before, see Build rootfs with buildroot section`